# Protractor - select element in repeater after $http call

Tags: ajax, angularjs, selenium, sails.js, protractor

I'm starting out on protractor testing of my sails.js / AngularJS app. Simplified, I have a following kind of ng-repeat in my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="book in books">
  book.name
</div>
```

My test clicks a button that sends a $http POST call to the server, creating another book, and upon success, adds another book to $scope.books. The problem is that the test fails since the book hasn't been created yet when the test checks for its existence. I know my locator/filter works since when running the test again (= the book exists before sending the call) the test succeeds.

Test:

```
    element.all(by.buttonText('Save')).
        filter(function(elem) {return elem.isDisplayed();}).
        first().
        click();

    browser.sleep(500); // even this doesn't work :(

    element.all(by.repeater('book in books')).filter(function(elem, index) {
        return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
            return text === "nameOfBook";
        });
    })
    .then(function(books) {
        expect(books[0].isPresent()).toEqual(true);
    });
```

So far the answers I've run into seem to suggest that protractor should automatically wait for the $http call to be finished before continuing, but in my case it doesn't seem to be so.

I even tried sleep times of 4000ms or so in which I can already see the new element in the repeater, but the test still sees the `books[0]` as `undefined`. The works when running the test again so the problem should not be in the filter but somewhere else.

Any insights on the matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [explicitly wait](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions) for the new book name to be present in the DOM:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

var elm = element(by.xpath("//div[. = 'nameOfBook']"));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 10000);
```

---

You can also wait for the count of elements in a repeater to increase:

```
var countOfElementsToBe = function(elms, expectedValue) {
  return elms.count().then(function (actualValue) {
      return expectedValue === actualValue;
  });
};

var books = element.all(by.repeater('book in books'));
books.count().then(function (booksCount) {
    browser.wait(countOfElementsToBe(books, booksCount + 1), 10000);
});
```

(not tested)

Comment: These seem like nice ways to bypass the problem. Thanks!